# cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key

Tags: sql

I have a `Varchar` column that has dates like `01/02/2020` and also 'N?A"
I want to create a computed column called `DateValue` with this expression:

```
(case when isdate([Value])=(1) then CONVERT(smalldatetime, [Value]) else null  end)
```

Then I want to put a nonclustered index on DateValue, but I get

> Column 'DateValue' in table 'dbo.tblTrkCustomDate' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.

Any idea around that?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Make the expression deterministic by including a style (and simplify with `TRY_CONVERT`): `TRY_CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, [Value], 103)` is indexable. (But not necessarily correct -- `01/02/2020` is ambiguous, after all, and you may want `110` instead.) Note that you can't have a column this way to opportunistically parse any old date format; in that case you'll need a new column of the correct type and a trigger. In all cases, converting/cleansing data once and keeping it typed correctly is preferable to doing it on the fly, index or no.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a detail in the creation of an index.  To be used in an index, the expression needs to be *deterministic*.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) describes:

> Expressions are deterministic if they always return the same result
>   for a specified set of inputs. The IsDeterministic property of the
>   COLUMNPROPERTY function reports whether a computed_column_expression
>   is deterministic.

Converting to a `smalldatetime` is [non-deterministic under these conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100 are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.

So, if you can choose one of the deterministic styles, then this should work.

Comment: So, do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: @DavidFetrow . . . I think the answer and the documentation is quite clear:  choose one of the styles that are permitted.